# How do I get HTTP header 'Content-Length' in API Gateway Lambda Proxy integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I need to build a function that takes 5 particular HTTP headers + the request params, aggregate, order, encode, and then hash them in order to validate/authenticate the overall request. However, I am unable to get the header 'Content-Length' to come through to the lambda.

I used Terraform to create the API Gateway (aws_api_gateway_domain_name) and then Serverless to create the endpoints:

```
functions:
  alerts:
    handler: src/event.handler
    role: arn:aws:iam::${env:AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:role/alerts_lambda
    environment:
      API_TRANS_KEY: ${env:API_TRANS_KEY}
      REGION: ${self:custom.region}
      SNS_ARN: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:${env:AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:Transactions
      STAGE: ${self:custom.deploymentStage}
    events:
      - http:
          path: /alerts/AccountEvent
          method: post
          cors: true
          integration: lambda-proxy
```

however the headers I get are :

```
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
        "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
        "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "US",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Date": "20170504:141752UTC",
        "Encryption-Type": "HMAC-SHA256",
        "Host": "events.dev.myapi.com",
        "Postman-Token": "84bd0cc3-f339-4b2a-8017-31ec9174c37e",
        "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.11.0",
        "User-ID": "galileo",
        "Via": "1.1 50c3c79d5d7adbc8948ea11709b61d17.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
        "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "1OE1aGP_3Q-CkXFuJbRwvkGAR2ZaHAPuozckZ6747EP64zZcmXjphw==",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5d0bf01b-8afdb9628f42a9357dbb5c68",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "73.72.58.46, 70.132.57.87",
        "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
    },
```

Do I need to use a mapping template at this point? Is CloudFront/Api Gateway stripping this header out for some reason (note, I don't set up a CloudFront distribution but API Gateway is creating one due to 'edge' type, but I could change it to 'regional' if that would solve this)?

Comment: Did you found a solution? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 5):

Based on my tests, the `Content-Length` header can be passed through when making an API request. However, it won't appear in the event payload for a Lambda proxy integration.

Two alternatives that you could use to receive the `Content-Length` header:

- Use an [HTTP API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api.html) with Lambda proxy integration instead of a REST API in API Gateway.
- Use a [Lambda non-proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-lambda-non-proxy-integration.html) for the REST API and configure it as follows:

  1. In the Mapping Templates for Integration Request:

     - Set `application/json` as the `Content-Type`
     - Change the default 'Method Passthrough Template' template by adding the statement - `"X-Content-Length" : $input.body.length()`
  2. In the Lambda function, the variable event `['X-Content-Length']` will contain the `Content-Length`.

Comment: Are you using an edge or regional endpoint type? However, your template mapping workaround of adding a length() function to body is elegant.

Comment: I tested using regional. However, even when using `edge optimized`, according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-headers-behavior), CloudFront should forward the `Content-Length` header to API Gateway. However, the header then seems to get dropped from the event payload of Lambda proxy.

Answer (score 0):

In the Integration Request stage of the API Gateway for a given endpoint, you can map header values to the body. You could also use the Integration Request step to move the lost headers into the body first. You may also be able to directly re-map it to the headers passed to the Lambda function as well.

More information on header/body mapping can be found here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html