# Adding required Content-Length header fails all requests to AWS API Gateway even when header present

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway REST API resource with a request validator that validates the request body and header params. Adding request body validation seems to require the `Content-Length` header be present (makes sense as the validator needs to know the length of the request body in order to validate it). Clients of the API were getting invalid responses to valid request bodies when this header was not present so I would like to return a validation message saying this header is missing rather than the generic invalid request message.

I set `Content-Length` as a required method header parameter and selected the 'Validate query string parameters and headers' request validator. When I tested this with a request including a `Content-Length` header I got the response:

```
{
    "message": "Missing required request parameters: [Content-Length]"
}
```

It seems as if the `Content-Length` header is in some way treated differently from other headers as when I try this with a dummy header such as `foo` it works as expected (request is accepted when header is set and rejected when it isn't).

Is there any way to get a combination of a body request validator and a required `Content-Length` header?

Comment: What type of request are you testing with? GET requests don't have a request body, so content-length doesn't make sense in that case.

Comment: @jordanm a POST with a request body

Comment: look like a duplication of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56693981/how-do-i-get-http-header-content-length-in-api-gateway-lambda-proxy-integratio

Comment: @MichalTsadok that ticket is about passing a `Content-Length` header value to a lambda proxy. I'm having problems with request validation within API Gateway before it passes anything to an integration. The latest with this is that I logged a ticket with AWS and it has gone into the abyss.